# Click and drag vs. two clicks to mark period on calendar. Which practice wins here?

Tags: drag-n-drop, calendar, click

I'm working on calendar app and we have a debate:

What's the best practice to mark a period:

Click and drag - like Google Calendar and AirBnb

or

2 Clicks to mark (first click starts the marking 2nd ends it)

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decide to go with your 2-clicks method, how do you differentiate between a user selecting a date for some other reason (ex: to add an event for that particular date) and them trying to mark the start of a period?

What I can think of is, you would have to introduce a button or some other type of input from the user to switch into a mode where they can make that kind of selection. And exit that mode when they select an end date.

Having the click and drag method eliminates the user having to perform those extra tasks (Looking for the button/option to switch modes, clicking the button). Therefore it seems like the better option.

But it's always better to test it out with your users because click and drag  requires users to have some prior experience with that type of ux.